# Calendar giving wrong day of week

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek

I have a calendar object as below that represents `08 Aug 2014`.It is a Friday. So  `myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` should be 6. But it gives 2. Why is that?

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1410177767000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Calcutta,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=37,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=8,DAY_OF_YEAR=251,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=32,SECOND=47,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I have a calendar object as below that represents 08 Aug 2014.

It doesn't: `MONTH=8` is September, not August (month numbering starts from zero).

You can verify yourself by noting `DAY_OF_YEAR=251` in your output. [The 251st day of a non-leap year is 8 September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_8).

Another way to check the timestamp is by pasting `1410177767000` into http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: 1+ That's why one should not use magic numbers but instead use the constants such as Month.AUGUST.

Comment: OMG. i have been debugging my code to death based on my wrong assumption.

Answer (score 4):

The GregorianCalender takes month for august as '7' and not '8' since January is represented as '0'.
Reference : [Gregorian Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int,%20int,%20int))

So kindly check the following and it should work.

```
   import java.util.*;

   public class Test {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           GregorianCalendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 7, 8);
           System.out.println(myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes rather than terrible legacy date-time classes with their crazy month numbering.

```
LocalDate                     // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, without offset, without time zone.
.of( 2014 , 8 , 8 )           // Or use `Month.AUGUST`.
.getDayOfWeek()               // Returns `DayOfWeek` enum object.
.equals( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY )   // Returns true/false.
```

> true

## java.time

You are using terrible app old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

### Sane numbering

Represent a date-only value with `LocalDate`. Note the sane numbering, unlike the legacy classes: `2014` means the year 2014, and months 1-12 mean January-December. So your problem of inadvertently using the wrong month is moot, and never would have occurred if you’d been using the modern and well-designed *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , 8 , 8 ) ;
```

For more clarity, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum. So month 8 is [`Month.AUGUST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#AUGUST).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.AUGUST , 8 ) ;
```

Ask for the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object representing the day-of-week on that date.

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

### Convert

If you have a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object in hand given by old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. [Convert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime()) to a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Then extract the `DayOfWeek`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As our friends said, the count starts from 0. So, January is month 0.

If you came here probably you have the code already done. In order to avoid reviews in code you could do:

```
currentDateMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

currentDateMonth = currentDateMonth+1;
```